# Selenium find element where ID attribute begin with unique characters and ends with random characters

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, findelement

This is the code for my button in HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="single_button618eda460b64617" title="">Re-attempt quiz</button>
```

and the class I define for many other component and the `id` always begin with `single_button`.

but the end is random character. And it's the only one that starts with this prefix.

How can i use `button=driver.find_element_by_id()`, but for the first `single_button`?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@id, 'single_button')]")

Answer (score 1):

As the element is the only where the prefix of the *`id`* attribute starts with this unique value you can use either of the following dynamic [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id^='single_button']")
  ```

> PS: `id^` denotes, value of *id* attribute starts with.

- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[starts-with(@id, 'single_button')]")
  ```